# Java: How to add multiple external libraries to makefile?

Tags: java, makefile, external, libraries

My java project makes use of some apache commons libraries. I want to be able to run my program in unix though so i made a makefile to compile it for me. My project has 4 Java classes and 4 external libraries (.jars). In my directory i have my four .Java files and a folder named "lib" which contain my .Jar files. Here's my make file:

```
 JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac -sourcepath / -classpath lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
$(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
SubmissionDriver.java \
FileAndArgs.java \
hashConverter.java \
InvalidAgeException.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

And here's my error messages: I get like 14 error message that pertain to the actual class files though. Here's some examples:

```
SubmissionDriver.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void httpSend() throws HttpException, IOException{
                                         ^
  symbol:   class HttpException
  location: class SubmissionDriver
SubmissionDriver.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
            HostConfiguration hf=new HostConfiguration();
            ^
 symbol:   class HostConfiguration
 location: class SubmissionDriver
SubmissionDriver.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
            HostConfiguration hf=new HostConfiguration();
                                     ^
 symbol:   class HostConfiguration
 location: class SubmissionDriver
SubmissionDriver.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
            PostMethod post = new PostMethod("myurl");
            ^
```

Also it states this at the bottom of thsoe 14 error messages:

```
14 errors
make: *** [SubmissionDriver.class] Error 1
```

Comment: Perhaps it's about time to use a builder designed for Java like Ant, Maven or Gradle.  These all integrate with your IDE and can be updated by your IDE.

Comment: I did assume this worked already in your IDE.  Are you sure your `import` statements in your code are correct?

Comment: Yeah all the code works correctly in eclipse

Comment: eclipse should have a plugin for ant, maven and gradle and it should be able to generate the builder for you.

Comment: Yeah i'm looking into that now, i've never worked with makefiles or those plugins before so i was hoping to avoid it but it seems like thats what i'll have to do.

Comment: `make` is not really suitable for even simple Java projects. I have seen it work, but it feels like the wrong tool for the job IMHO.

Comment: So once i create my ant file, how would i run the program via command line?

Comment: In maven I would use `assembly:assembly` and it would create a directory of the jars I need and start up script.  There must be a tool in ant to do this as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So i've created my ant file and ran the ant command successfully but i dont knwo how to run the actual program

Comment: You need to create a shell script which will start `java %JVM_OPTS% -cp %MY_CLASSPATH% mypackage.MyClass %MY_ARGS%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make is not a good build tool for java. Try ant perhaps (or Maven,
   or Gradle)
2. The way your makefile is structured you invoke a "javac" command for each java class. This will not work if your java classes have dependencies on each other
3. Make sure you have a tab before this line

   $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

Comment: Make sure you double check the tab before $(RM) as well. When moving from windows to *nix make files tend to break